# How to refresh login using web sdk in React Native?

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions

I'm using the Firebase web sdk (JS) in a ReactNative app.  My login is simple:

```
firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
```

it works fine.  However, if the user backgrounds my app and comes back a few hours later, they are logged out (without them having explicitly logged out and without my app logging them out).  There seems to be a 1 hour timeout on the login token but Firebase is NOT refreshing this token when the app is backgrounded or when the app comes back to the foreground.

This is a bad experience for my users since they are forced to login again when they come back the next day.

How can I force the Firebase SDK to refresh the login token even if the app is backgrounded or when it comes back into the foreground?

Or can I refresh it myself somehow when the app comes back to the foreground after a few hours?

Thanks!

Comment: I doubt it. Just for confirmation, did you check whether user is logged-in or not? Or everytime you are just showing login screen whenever user restarts the app. Because what i am guessing here is, if user is coming back to the app after several time, app will be restart and user is again seeing login screen. Might me some login logic is missing.

Comment: My best guess based on what you shared is below. If that's not it, can you show how you detect that the user isn't logged in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was entirely my fault.  I had a line in my App.js render method like:

```
// Should have been wrapped in an if
store.dispatch(FirebaseAuth.signOutCurrentUser());

// XXX TODO login as known user for testing, DO NOT USE IN PRODUCTION
const autoLogoutAndLoginAsTestAccount = false;
if (__DEV__ && autoLogoutAndLoginAsTestAccount) {
  store.dispatch(FirebaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword({ email: "joel@test.com", password: "REDACTED" }));
}
```

which should have been

```
// XXX TODO login as known user for testing, DO NOT USE IN PRODUCTION
const autoLogoutAndLoginAsTestAccount = false;
if (__DEV__ && autoLogoutAndLoginAsTestAccount) {
  store.dispatch(FirebaseAuth.signOutCurrentUser());
  store.dispatch(FirebaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword({ email: "joel@test.com", password: "REDACTED" }));
}
```

I had this in place so I wouldn't need to login each time I hot reloaded the RN code but although I had wrapped the autologin inside an if to prevent it from running in prod/testflight, I had not wrapped the autologout.  So Firebase was doing what I asked it to and logging out the user every time it re-rendered the app (e.g. on restart).

I was using an auth listener and that was not the issue.

Sorry, this was a foolish mistake on my part and I feel embarassed since I'm normally very careful with my code and I just missed this.  I didn't mean to waste anybody's time and thanks all for your careful answers.  I'm posting this here in case it helps somebody in future.

Answer (score 2):

Authentication state is automatically persisted across application restarts. But it will have to be loaded, and verified against the server, since the ID token expires each hour

My initial guess would be that the user state simply hasn't been restored yet, which you solve by using an auto state listener.

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function (user) {
  if (user) {
    ... user is signed in
  }
  else {
    ... user is NOT signed in, show login screen
  }
})
```

Also check out this [checking the current authentication state](https://blog.invertase.io/getting-started-with-firebase-authentication-on-react-native-a1ed3d2d6d91#da78) in this blog post, which has an example of how to use the above approach in your React Native code.

Comment: thanks as always.  Your quick answer and careful attention to detail is always welcome and we Firebase users appreciate all that you do for us!  :-)